# JDO Annontations: renaming columns across a hierarchy several levels deep

Tags: google-app-engine, tomcat, annotations, jdo, datanucleus

I'm trying to define three classes using JDO annotations. Level3 has two embedded members of type Level2 and Level2 has one embedded member of type Level1. Like this:

```
@PersistenceCapable
@EmbeddedOnly
public class Level1 {
  @Persistent
  private Long lvl1_;
}

@PersistenceCapable
@EmbeddedOnly
public class Level2 {
  @Persistent
  @Embedded(members = {
    @Persistent(name="lvl1_", columns=@Column(name="lvl1inlvl2_")),
  })
  private Level1 lvl1embedded_;
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class Level3 {
  @Persistent
  @Embedded(members = {
    @Persistent(name="lvl1embedded_",columns=@Column(name="lvl1inlvl3first_")),
  })
  private Level2 lvl2embeddedfirst_;

  @Persistent
  @Embedded(members = {
    @Persistent(name="lvl1embedded_",columns=@Column(name="lvl1inlvl3second_")),
  })
  private Level2 lvl2embeddedsecond_;
}
```

I'm renaming the member of Level1 in Level2 and the member of Level2 in Level3.
This works in the Google App Engine, but trying to run it Tomcat throws this exception:

```
Duplicate column name "`LVL1_`" defined for table "`LEVEL3`". You cannot map multiple fields to the same column. The duplicated columns are specified by Level1.lvl1_ and Level1.lvl1_
```

An option could be to remove the class Level1 and copy the code into Level2 but I have several other classes embedding Level1 so I don't want to have the same code repeated pretty much everywhere.

I've tried using a dot notation to reference the members of Level1 from Level3 but it doesn't work:

```
@Embedded(members = {
  @Persistent(name="Level1.lvl1_",columns=@Column(name="lvl1inlvl3second_")),
})
```

The enhancer throws errors like this:

```
Class Level3 has field Level1.lvl1_ declared in MetaData, but this field doesnt exist in the class!
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

PS: btw, this is my first question, be kind :)

---

For completeness shake, following the answer below, the XML metadata for Level3 should be something like this:

```
<class name="Level3"
       persistence-modifier="persistence-capable"
       table="LEVEL3">

  <field name="lvl2embeddedfirst_"
         persistence-modifier="persistent">
    <embedded>
      <field name="lvl1embedded" column="level3lvl1embedded">
        <embedded>
          <field name="lvl1_" column="level3lvl1_"/>
        </embedded>
      </field>
    </embedded>
  </field>
</class>
```

Comment: What does 'run it in Tomcat' mean? you maybe have some datastore of some undefined type

Comment: I think "run in Tomcat" means Tomcat + Mysql + datanucleus rdbms? Is that what you are asking? I see the "Duplicate column name" error in the Tomcat logs.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: OK, using RDBMS then. Since it is possible to use Tomcat with many other types of datastores too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAE datastore (and plugin) don't check for duplicate column (property) name (which you have with the field of the Level1 of the 2 Level2s) - which is a bug in GAE. RDBMS DataNucleus plugin (and the RDBMS datastore) DOES check for duplicate columns (and throws an exception).

Using annotations there is (currently) no way to specify the column override on nested embedded objects. You can however specify the column overrides using XML (package.jdo file). But then specifying ORM specific information is ALWAYS recommended to be done in an XML file

Comment: Great answer, thanks! You can keep annotations and just write the XML for class Level3 (XML has higher priority).